# Vectorspace of linear functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I already proved that $R_W : L(X,Y) \longrightarrow L(W,Y), \quad R_W(A) := A|_W \quad \text{for} \quad W \subseteq X $ is a continous function and $|| R_W(A) || \leq 1$.

Let $X=X_1 \times X_2$ for normed Vectorspaces $X_i$. 
Show for a topological $M$ and all $f:M \longrightarrow L(X,Y) :$
$$f \quad\text{continous} \Longleftrightarrow R_{X_1} \circ f \quad \text{and} \quad  R_{X_2} \circ f \quad \text{continous}$$

$" \Longrightarrow" $ is clear but im having problems showing $" \Longleftarrow"$

$L(X,Y)$ = Vector space of linear functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for any $A \in L(X, Y)$ and $(x_1,x_2) \in X_1 \times X_2$, we have $A(x_1,x_2) = R_{X_1}(A)(x_1) + R_{X_2}(A)(x_2)$.